# JQuery - Mouseleave not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have replicated my problem here - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2knw3s/).

On mouseleave, the reverse animate effect just disappears.

I think it has something to do with the "display" property, but I'm not sure how to resolve this. I guess the reason this happens is due to the "display:block" on hover, but then it reverts to display:none?

If I then force "display:block" on the submenu element, it shows all submenu options at once.

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul class="level-2">
    <li class="has-child"> <a href="/clients/">Clients</a>
      <ul class="sublevel level-3 submenu">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a href="/clients/test1/">Test1</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-child"> <a href="/services/">Services</a>
      <ul class="sublevel level-3 submenu">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a href="/services/test2/">Test2</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.level-2 li').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $('.submenu').stop().animate({ 'margin-left':"300px" }, 1000);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $('.submenu').stop().animate({ 'margin-left':"-200px" }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `display: none` assigned to `.submenu` rule, so as soon as you move the cursor out of the element the `display` is set to `none` which will remove the item from being rendered.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.level-2 > li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $('.submenu', this).stop().removeClass('hidden').animate({
        'margin-left': "300px"
      }, 1000);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $('.submenu', this).stop().animate({
        'margin-left': "-200px"
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
nav ul li a {
  list-style: none;
  color: #cccccc;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.submenu {
  position: fixed;
  left: -120px;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3a4247 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="level-2">
    <li class="has-child"> <a href="/clients/">Clients</a>
      <ul class="sublevel level-3 submenu">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a href="/clients/test1/">Test1</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-child"> <a href="/services/">Services</a>
      <ul class="sublevel level-3 submenu">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a href="/services/test2/">Test2</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly Arun, that made sense :)